# How to create two divs where one of them will be fixed and other will be scrollable

Tags: html, css, fixed, scrollable

I have one div which will hold my main contents and will be scrollable; and there is another div(footer) at the bottom exactly below the content div which will be fixed; the catch here is, no matter what the size of the browser window is, the main content div should not hide behind the footer div and it should resize its height based on the height of the browser. 
So basically, i want both of them to be fixed at their positions and main div should always be scrollable.
So far whatever i have tried had made my scrollable div hide its content behind the footer.
I hope my question is not confusing.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/0C0wDqM.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex layout will really help you here:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="content">content</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column
}

#content {
    flex:1;
    overflow:auto;
}
#footer {
    height:50px;  /* Whatever fixed height you desire */
}
```

**Example**:

http://jsfiddle.net/0qhevkbn/

Comment: Hey, the example shows exactly what i need, but now the problem is the moment i remove the other styling like position of the footer, it goes directly below the header. And when i decrease the height of the browser the content gets hidden by the footer.

Comment: @TeddyPayne Make sure that `body` or some wrapping container for the content and footer elements has the `display: flex` style.  If you already have that, try starting with the example code and changing it one line at a time to match your needs, and see exactly which change causes your layout to break.  If you post your markup and styles or link to a jsfiddle, I could help you see what is causing the problem.